# Latin numbers at start of sentences in Arabic

Tags: javascript, html, css, arabic

I have a sentence written in Arabic that reads from right to left with a number at the start. When added to a webpage the browser appears to automatically move the number to the end of the sentence - something I imagine is to do with a mixture of latin and arabic text. Do any Arabic devs, or someone with a good knowledge of dealing with arabic text on the web, know a workaround for this that keeps the number at the start of the sentence on the far right of the text?

Comment: That number is composed of western digits (ASCII), as opposed to [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals) seen in some areas where the Arabic language is used?

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use `float` and `direction`

```css
.arabic{
  background: red;
  direction: rtl;
}
.latinnumber{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="arabic">
  <span class="latinnumber">.1 </span>
  sfkdsngj fdgfbg bfgb hjbrfgj bjrfgbj 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution where the text does not need to be broken up into different elements as the site I'm working on loads different languages into each section of text. There must be a way to do this as I've seen it on arabic websites. On these sites the number is still shown at the end of the sentence on the left of the text in inspector, but is rendered correctly at the start of the sentence on the far right.